# Best way to drop/create a replicated table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactional-replication

I have SQL Server Replication set up to replicate several tables for an accounting application. It's using transaction replication with an initial snapshot. There around about 100 subscribers.

I am trying to figure out the best way to update replicated tables. Right now, when we do an update the end user has to run a utility that upgrades tables by moving data to a temp table, dropping the table, then recreating the table based on the new table definition. The problem is replicated tables cannot be dropped.

So far I've researched and tried a few things. From what i've found out in order to drop/create a replicated table the Article has to be dropped, but it can only be dropped if all subscriptions are dropped. That means in order to upgrade a table I'll have to drop all articles and subscriptions, and then totally recreate the publication.

This is a pain, because this will require quite a bit of refactoring. Also the primary concern is the time it will take to re-do the replication to all 100 subscribers. So i was wondering if there's a better way to handle dropping/creating replicated tables.

Thanks,
Makolyte

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eadc7694-c587-48b3-9c64-595c694c699f/dropping-table-in-after-transaction-log-replication?forum=sqldisasterrecovery#56d0b44b-0ff8-4081-8be3-92d4582395eb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd question why you're replicating a table that's changing schema so frequently. That said, you have a couple of options.

1. Make your table changes in such a way as they're compatible with replication. See [Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).
2. If that's not possible, drop the subscribers from the article with sp_dropsubscription and drop the article with sp_droparticle. Make your table changes, re-add the article with sp_addarticle, re-add the subscribers with sp_addsubscription, and run the snapshot agent to create a snapshot of the newly added article.

Comment: The first option would require changing that old conversion tool a lot. With the second option, would all subscribers need to be reinitialized since the snapshot is invalidated? Or would they be ok since it's transactional replication?

Comment: Once you drop the subscribers, they'll all need to be re-initialized since they're no longer subscribing to the publication.